# Error "gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory" while compiling Nachos source code

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, mips, cross-compiling, nachos

I am trying to install Nachos on my laptop and I have Ubuntu 11.04 on the laptop.

The code is in C and so to build it  I assume I will need cross compiler. This is where my problem is. I downloaded the source code of the MIPS cross compiler using the command

```
  wget http://mll.csie.ntu.edu.tw/course/os_f08/assignment/mips-decstation.linux-xgcc.gz
```

and I unzipped it using

```
tar zxvf mips-decstation.linux-xgcc.gz
```

This is okay, but when I try to build the source code of the nachos os, using make, I get this error -

```
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. make: *** [bitmap.o] Error 1
```

I am trying to follow the instructions given over here - http://mll.csie.ntu.edu.tw/course/os_f08/217.htm and everything is working fine except when I try to use make.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, the program now starts to compile but I get this error _ 

 
Hi, now i have this error - /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++ /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [nachos] Error 1 any ideas on how to fix this ?

What should I do about this ?

Answer (score 412, accepted):

You're missing the 32 bit libc dev package:

On **Ubuntu** it's called libc6-dev-i386 - do `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386`. See below for extra instructions for Ubuntu 12.04.

On **Red Hat** distros, the package name is `glibc-devel.i686` (Thanks to David Gardner's  comment).

On **CentOS 5.8**, the package name is `glibc-devel.i386` (Thanks to JimKleck's comment).

On **CentOS 6 / 7**, the package name is `glibc-devel.i686`.

On **SLES** it's called glibc-devel-32bit - do `zypper in glibc-devel-32bit`.

On **Gentoo** it's called `sys-libs/glibc` - do `emerge -1a sys-libs/gcc` 
[[source](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-501993.html)] (Note : One may use `equery` to confirm this is correct; do `equery belongs belongs /usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h`)

On **ArchLinux**, the package name is `lib32-glibc` - do `pacman -S lib32-glibc`.

---

Are you using **Ubuntu 12.04**? There is [a known problem that puts the files in a non standard location](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-02/msg00314.html). You'll [also](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=682678) need to do:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
```

somewhere before you build (say in your .bashrc).

---

If you are also compiling C++ code, you will also need the 32 bit stdc++ library. If you see this warning:

> .... /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ ....

On **Ubuntu**  you will need to do  `sudo apt-get install g++-multilib`

On **CentOS 5** you will need to do `yum install libstdc++-devel.i386`

On **CentOS 6** you will need to do `yum install libstdc++-devel.i686`

Please feel free to edit in the packages for other systems.

Comment: Maybe the reason I didn't find that package is that my laptop is 32 bit...I did however find `libc-dev-amd64`.  My bad.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say he's probably on a 64 bit machine, which is why the file is missing. On my 64 bit machine, stubs.h (which he has) is in libc6-dev, while stubs-32.h (which he doesn't) is in libc6-dev-i386. Good tip about apt-file - I didn't know about it :)

Comment: There is a known problem on Ubuntu 12.04 that puts this file in a non-standard directory after installation. This solution worked for me in the end http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-02/msg00314.html.

Comment: Thanks @e_x_p. I've added these extra instructions.

Comment: on fedora 19 i had to install glibc-devel.i686 instead (i686 vs i386).

Comment: What if you are not su on your machine?

Comment: To avoid linker error you'll also need a 32 bits libgcc (`libgcc.i686` on fedora)

Comment: so, is it not the case that the OP would just need to direct the installation to use the 64-bit version of stubs that's already present?  the OP needs to install the 32-bit version even though the installation is (potentially) taking place on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: **fedora** `sudo dnf install glibc-devel.i686`

Answer (score 58):

From the [GNU UPC website](http://www.gccupc.org/faq/article/compiler_build_fails_with_fatal_error_gnu_stubs_32.h_no_such_file_or_directory.html):

> Compiler build fails with fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or
>   directory
>
> This error message shows up on the 64 bit systems where GCC/UPC
>   multilib feature is enabled, and it indicates that 32 bit version of
>   libc is not installed. There are two ways to correct this problem:
>
> - Install 32 bit version of glibc (e.g. glibc-devel.i686 on Fedora,
>     CentOS, ..)
> - Disable 'multilib' build by supplying "--disable-multilib"
>     switch on the compiler configuration command

Comment: thank you for a particularly useful answer: the `--disable-multilib` part

Comment: @djhaskin987, gccupc.org is not the source, gcc.gnu.org is

Comment: I did 'yum install glibc-devel.i686' on x64 centos 6.4

Comment: How do you do this with an autoconf based make system? I've tried passing --disable-multilib, but it doesn't change anything. I don't have root access to install the multilib package.

Comment: This solves my question that why I have to specify `.i686` architecture when my machine is `x86_64`

Answer (score 9):

Try doing a `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`.

`apt-file` tells me that the file in question belongs to that package.

Comment: This is not sufficient on a multiarch machine since you'll still get this error even if you have the latest version of libc6-dev installed.

Answer (score 7):

This is now in the GCC wiki FAQ, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#gnu_stubs-32.h

Answer (score 2):

Hmm well I am on ubuntu 12.04 and I got this same error when trying to compile gcc 4.7.2

I tried installing the `libc6-dev-i386` package and got the following:

```
Package libc6-dev-i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libc6-dev-i386' has no installation candidate
```

I also set the correct environment variables in bash:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
```

however, I was still getting the error then I simply copied `stubs-32.h` over to where gcc was expecting to find it after doing a quick diff:

```
vic@ubuntu:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu$ diff ../../gnu ./
Only in ./: stubs-32.h
Only in ../../gnu: stubs-64.h
vic@ubuntu:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu$ sudo cp stubs-32.h ../../gnu/
[sudo] password for vic: 
vic@ubuntu:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu$ diff ../../gnu ./
Only in ../../gnu: stubs-64.h
vic@ubuntu:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu$
```

It's compiling now, let's see if it complains more ...

Comment: Odd. That package is definitely available in 12.04 (Precise) see http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libc6-dev-i386

Comment: I faced this issue while running on VS Code in linux. Adding "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu" to c_cpp_properties.json file's includePath array worked perfect for me. Thanks to your answer I found the location of this file.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting following error on a fedora 18 box:

---

1.
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

I Installed glibc.i686 and glibc-devel.i686, then compilation failed with following error:

2.
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Solution:

I installed (yum install) glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i386 and libgcc.i686 to get rid of the compilation issue.

Now compilation for 32 bit (-m32) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it smells like an error (or at least a potential source of future pain) to be using files from /usr/include when cross-compiling.

Comment: I think that he is trying to build the toolchain, not cross-compile with those includes.

Answer (score 0):

`gnu/stubs-32.h` is not directed included in programms. It's a back-end type header file of `gnu/stubs.h`, just like `gnu/stubs-64.h`. You can install the `multilib` package to add both.

Answer (score 0):

**# sudo apt-get install g++-multilib**

Should fix this error on 64-bit machines (Debian/Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in Mac-OSX terminal with python, try updating the versions of the packages you are using. So, go to your files in python and where you specified the packages, update them to the latest versions available on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/Ubuntu use:

`sudo apt-get install g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Arch Linux like me. You can try

- sudo pacman -S lib32-gcc-libs

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi，I encountered the same question. When I add '-D__TARGET_ARCH_x86' in MAKEFILE, it worked!

The the error message is like:

```
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:26:
In file included from /usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h:33:
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:452:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:11: fatal error: 'gnu/stubs-32.h' file not found
# include <gnu/stubs-32.h>nter code here
```

The content in stubs.h is

```
#if !defined __x86_64__
# include <gnu/stubs-32.h>
#endif
#if defined __x86_64__ && defined __LP64__
# include <gnu/stubs-64.h>
#endif
#if defined __x86_64__ && defined __ILP32__
# include <gnu/stubs-x32.h>
#endif
```

you could find the real reason is the missing of macro definition **x86_64**. The compilor has to find stubs-x32.h. So you can install glibc with 32bits to solve the question. But the better way is to specific the arch as 64bits。You only need to add '-D__TARGET_ARCH_x86' in gcc&g++ command in MAKEFILE.