# /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, gnu, i386

I am trying to install `roccc 2.0`. I have installed required packages. Now while installing it, it is giving me this error:

```
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
```

I searched for `gnu/stubs-32.h` and came to know, for Linux 64-bit its in `glibc-devel` and for Linux 32-bit, its in `libc6-dev-i386`.

I am using Linux 32-bit: i386 GNU/Linux, but couldn't get the `lib` required to resolve this error.

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 15):

If your Linux distro is Redhat based (Fedora/CentOS/RHEL):

```
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

#### References

- [Original post answer solved this problem RHEL x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 3):

Header file `gnu/stubs-32.h` is under `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/` but the install script tries to find it in `/usr/include/`, try this quick fix to complete the installation:

`sudo ln -s /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-32.h /usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h`

After installation is finished, you can delete the link.

Answer (score 1):

The package name keeps on changing, just do a

```
yum list glibc-devel
```

to find out current package for 32 bit. In my case it only listed 2 packages one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit. I just installed the 32 bit  using

```
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

Install 'glibc-devel' package, or whatever it called in your distro. You may also need to install ia32-libs lib32z1-dev lib32bz2-dev (names could be different in your distro).

Comment: what i have done is:   command1: apt-file search stubs-32.h output:libc6-dev: /usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h

command2:apt-get install libc6-dev but still there is same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The script is trying to get stubs-32.h from /usr/include/ where it is not found. To solve this you have to add an "include" path (by default it is `/usr/include`) like this:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

OR

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
```

You can visit [Error "gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory" while compiling Nachos source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory) for additional reference.

Answer (score 0):

If on a Red Hat distro such as Fedora/CentOS/RHEL you can do the following to find out what package provides a given file:

```
$ repoquery -qf */stubs-32.h
glibc-devel-0:2.17-260.el7.i686
```

And then install it:

```
$ sudo yum install -y glibc-devel-0:2.17-260.el7.i686
```