# How to find packages containing a specific file?

Tags: linux, package, yum, apt

I want to find out which packages (if any) contain a specific file name. For instance, I'm trying to compile 32-bit programs in a 64-bit machine and GCC complains about a missing file "gnu/stubs-32.h". How can I quickly find which package I should install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a Debian-based distribution, you can use apt-file:

`apt-file search path/to/filename` (but for it to work, you must first populate the database, running `apt-file update` as root)

If using an RPM-based distribution (Red Hat, Fedora, etc), there is the equivalent `yum provides`: `yum provides path/to/filename`, which supports wildcards (for instance: `yum provides \*/gnu/stubs-32.h`).

Answer (score 0):

A quick [google search](https://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=gnu/stubs-32.h&redir_esc=&ei=gW9pUIrGG-bP0QW7soCgCA) would also point you to a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory) stackoverflow question. There  you will find out that you need the 32 bit libc-dev package (libc6-dev-i386).

Comment: I actually got the example from that question, but the idea of the question was to be more generic: given an arbitrary file name, how to find which packages contain it? The libc example was just to illustrate, but I could find it useful to look for, let's say, all packages which contain references to pthread.h.
I did a quick SO search and didn't find a question that seemed similar enought, but if there is one please tell me so I can close this (and find out what was missing in my original search).

Comment: My apologies, in that case @dhekir already answered the question.

Comment: No problem, it's the first time I use the "ask-and-answer in Q&A style", so maybe it should be better rephrased? Any suggestions welcome.