# CMake looking for Qt libraries in the wrong path on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake

CMake on ubuntu is giving me the following error

```
CMake Error at blah/CMakeLists.txt:19 (ADD_LIBRARY)
Cannot find source file:
    /usr/lib/libQtGui.so
```

The relevant part of CMakeLists.txt is this

```
FIND_PACKAGE (Qt4 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${QT_INCLUDES})
QT4_WRAP_CPP (QT_SRCS ${HEADERS})
ADD_LIBRARY (blah ${CPP} ${QT_SRCS} ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

A little investigation shows that libQtGui.so and its friends live in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` (which is [correct](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libQtGui)) instead of `/usr/lib` as CMake thinks it does.

This build environment worked fine a few months ago. No source or config files have changed, but the software packages have been routinely updated.

What has changed? How can I fix this?

Comment: First off, you shouldn't be putting `${QT_LIBRARIES}` into the list of source files. This variable is designed for use in `target_link_libraries(blah ${QT_LIBRARIES})`. Does the problem persist if you use it like that?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory), the problem is that Ubuntu 12.04 installs libraries to nonstandard paths.

The fix is

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
```