# Eclipse can't find stubs.h

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I get this error whenever I want to build a program in eclipse.

```
fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
make: ***[test] Error 1
```

And this is my simple program

```
 #include <cstdio>

 int main(){
     printf("Hello");
 }
```

How to fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit.
Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: (@Ogrim - thanks, added a Close vote)

Comment: I have tried it but still got the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors indicate that the supporting 32-bit libraries have not been properly installed!

So you have install missing libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/$(gcc -print-multiarch)
```

Save the export instructions (for example in your .bashrc).

To test on the fly:

- close eclipse
- open a console
- type exports instructions
- launch eclipse from console

Question is answered also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory).

**edit**

Your problem is that you have **gcc** in

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Instead that in:

```
/usr/lib
```

So check this solution:

- open a console
- export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
- sudo ldconfig
- launch eclipse

Comment: I got this output when tried to install libc6-dev-i386.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6-dev-i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libc6-dev-i386' has no installation candidate

Comment: take a look to the edit

Comment: maybe is not necessaries the export.. test it and let me know..

Comment: Just when I try `export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/$(gcc -print-multiarch)` I got these output.
`gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-print-multiarch’`
`gcc: fatal error: no input files`
`compilation terminated.` Is this normal?

Comment: maybe you have an old gcc.. what's the result of "gcc --version"  ?

Comment: this is output from `gcc --version`. "gcc (GCC) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE."

Comment: And this is output from `gcc -v`. "Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.1/configure --disable-checking --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-multiarch --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --program-suffix=-4.6 --with-gmp=/usr/local/lib --with-mpc=/usr/lib --with-mpfr=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --with-system-zlib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC)"

Comment: that effort! look at last edit, maybe is only a location problem.. gcc  usually is in /usr/lib

Comment: I got this error when `sudo ldconfig`. "/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.16-gdb.py is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start." Why is it?

Comment: sorry I've post you the wrong export, close the console and test in another.. hope it works..

Comment: Thanks. I happen to found a solution for this. I've found that if I copy stubs-32.h from /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu to '/usr/include/gnu` then I can compile the program. I still don't understand why I need to copy it though?