# Error while compiling a C program using GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I am very new to using GCC in Linux. I have written a sample C program,when I try and run the C program in command line using `gcc file.c`, it gives me the following errors:

```
​In file included from /usr/include/features.h:388:0,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:25,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/include/limits.h:168,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/include/limits.h:34,
                 from adder_test_gen.c:1:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:10:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory
 # include <gnu/stubs-64.h>
                           ^
```

When I type `which gcc`, I get the location of the installed file, I get the version number as:

```
\gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If `gcc --version` doesn't work, then most likely it was installed incorrectly. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: Now wasn't showing the version, but now it is. Its college computer , so I cannot reinstall

Comment: are you sure that directory exisits and the compiler can find it?

Comment: Yes, I also get the  version number

Comment: It seems you are missing the `glibc-devel` package which contains the `stubs-64.h` file.  Google would have told you so.  If you cannot install software (i.e. have no root access) there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: IF `gnu/stubs-64.h` is not installed at `/usr/include` AND you can't fix the installation THEN ask the administrator.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/error-gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-compiling-nachos-source .

Comment: can you compile a file containing just `main();` ?

Comment: I cannot compile main();

Comment: Please show us your code!