# Cross-compiling c++ SFML from ubuntu to windows

Tags: c++, ubuntu, c++11, cross-compiling, sfml

I am using ming, and it works for cross-compiling. When using SFML for ubuntu it works with no problem too. When I combine it:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -I/usr/include -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe  -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics
```

error I got is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:27:0,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/cwchar:44,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/ios:38,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
             from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
             from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
             from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
             from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/features.h:398:23: fatal error: gnu/stubs.h: No such file or directory
#include <gnu/stubs.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: You haven't provided the include path. You have to insert `-Ipath/to/SFML/include`

Comment: AM sorry but i cant find SFML, I installed it using only sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev . Should i download and include path to that or... sorry for my little knowlage

Comment: Check inside usr/lib or lib.

Comment: Couldnt find it there.

Comment: I found it it in usr/include/SFML , there i can see .hpp files i need. but i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -Iusr/include/SFML -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe  -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics  still gives same error

Comment: `-I/usr/include` seems better.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/error-gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-compiling-nachos-source
installed:
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
I get now huge amount of errors, one part of it looks like :
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/cmath: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/cmath:1038:11: error: ‘::double_t’ has not been declared
   using ::double_t;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/cmath:1039:11: error: ‘::float_t’ has not been declare

Comment: @EdinDedić This is mere speculation, but I think that may be a sign that you're using the wrong installation. Are you running that code on Windows? Linux? If so, you need to use the correct version that's found on the SFML download site.