# I'm trying to build an android app in Qt5.4. Error: #include <gnu/stubs.h> -- no such file or directory. (Not stubs-32.h!))

Tags: android, c++, qt, c++11

Here's my (mess of a) .pro file. I thought the problem may be here.

```
    TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick

SOURCES += main.cpp \
mysteamclass.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

DISTFILES +=

HEADERS += \
mysteamclass.h
#--------------------------------ME= C++11 AND    LIBRARIES-----------------#

CONFIG+=c++11


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/freesteam

DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/include


 LIBS += -L/usr/local/include/

# LIBS += -L/usr/local/include -lgsl

# LIBS += -L/usr/local/include -libfreesteam
 LIBS += -L/usr/local/include -lgslcblas

LIBS+= -L/usr/lib/freesteam



win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/release/ -lfreesteam
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/debug/ -lfreesteam
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/ -lfreesteam

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
```

Here's some code that's close to the #include, after following the error link on QtCreator.

```
    /* This is here only because every header file already includes this one.
   Get the definitions of all the appropriate `__stub_FUNCTION' symbols.
   <gnu/stubs.h> contains `#define __stub_FUNCTION' when FUNCTION is a stub
   that will always return failure (and set errno to ENOSYS).  */
#include <gnu/stubs.h>


#endif  /* features.h  */
```

Any thoughts on how (if) I could resolve this?

EDIT: Forgot to add that I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 x64.

Edit to explain why this is NOT a duplicate of the linked question (like already stated in the title of this question).

The most upvoted answer there gives instructions on how to install something called "libc6-dev-i386". Well, my problem is that I don't get the error "gnu/stubs-32.h" is missing but **"gnu/stubs.h"**. I'm assuming that my problem is something else since I'm not doing anything with 32 bits here nor am I trying to install nachos (whatever that might be).

The second most upvoted answer suggests basically the same thing. Install a 32 bit version of glibc. Again, I don't have any problems with a 32bit version thing. 
The next option on this answer is  disable multilib by giving "--disable-" multilib" to the compiler configuration. But I can't do this. I don't know how/where to add compiler configurations for Qt.

Another answer says I should install "libc6-dev". I did, it didn't help.

I also tried installing the multilib, as suggested by one of the answrs, since I'm using a x64 machine. Again zilch. :-)

Comment: Do you have the libc6-dev package installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory" while compiling Nachos source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/error-gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-compiling-nachos-source)

Comment: @sashoalm Nothing over there helped me with the problem. Like already stated on the question, the error is not "gnu/stubs-32.h" ubt "gnu/stubs.h" and I certainly am not trying to install any nachos or anything else. I'm just trying to compile (build ) an android application on Qt5.4.

Comment: @TimSmit Thanks for the comment. I installed it but it didn't help that much.

Comment: If the problem persists and you have a multi-arch system, try adding "LIBS+= -L/usr/lib64" to your project file or maybe build a 32-bits executable to see if the problem is solved then (CONFIG += m32)