# ACTUALLY I AM TRYING TO RUN A COMMAND IN TOPSPIN3.2

Tags: gcc, gnu

i am running a program with compiler environment gnu but finally, when I run any command in my program named topspin3.2 I am encountering this error, so I kindly request anyone to help me to rectify this error

In file included from /opt/topspin3.2/gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include-fixed/features.h:328:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from humpcal.c:30:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

### exit 1

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT! many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing 32 bit versions of standard development libraries for C. See also [Error "gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory" while compiling Nachos source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548).

Comment: thank you very much, I finally rectified error and now I fixed the problem with compilation