# Android Studio NDK : 'gnu/stubs.h' file not found

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm using Android Studio to create a JNI module, here's my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC -std=c++11")

# include deps headers
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/3rdparty/re2
                    /usr/include)

# JNI Support
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/jdk1.8.0_111/include
                    /jdk1.8.0_111/include/linux)

file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_SRC  "src/mypackage/*.cpp")

ADD_LIBRARY(my_target SHARED api.cpp ${MY_SRC})
```

#### /usr/include

The first clue is, this program can't find system headers itself, I need to include `/usr/include` with `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. e.g. it can't find `boost/version.hpp` unless I include `/usr/include`.

#### Problem

This program turns out a fatal error : `Error:(391, 10) fatal error: 'gnu/stubs.h' file not found`. It's so wired, I never uses `stubs.h`.

Then I found there is a `stub.h` in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`, so I include it as well, but then there's a `Error:(7, 11) fatal error: 'gnu/stubs-32.h' file not found` and I don't have it in my system. How can I deal with these kind of problem, and I never uses `stubs-32.h` in my program, shouldn't it be packaged into boost library (if it is required by boost)?

Comment: Hi. Did you look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/error-gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-compiling-nachos-source. It talks about installing some libs that might be missing.

Comment: Be careful with the include directories you are using. You are including a path to the system includes, but they could not be compatible with the libraries you are adding to android application. This could be a problem if you are using different versions (of the boost library for example) in your linux machine and in your android app.