# fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to build gcc 7.2.0.  I get this error:

```
fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
```

I don't have root access or sudo access on this machine so I cannot use apt.  What source package can I install that will resolve this?

Comment: gcc 7.3.0 → item 7 →  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915 ......... Build gcc : Usually solved with a copy of stubs-32.h to `/usr/include/gnu/`  https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h.html  ........ Or do `yum install glibc-devel.i686`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory" while compiling Nachos source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/error-gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-compiling-nachos-source)

Comment: sudo dnf install glibc-devel.i686

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `glibc-devel`, see https://www.question-defense.com/2010/03/09/usrincludegnustubs-h727-error-gnustubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7412698/6723250.